# Applying functions to list elements selectively

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got two lists that contain an element identifier and a number:

```
list1 = Transpose[{{"c", "a", "b"}, {2, 1, 1}}]
list2 = Transpose[{{"a", "b", "c", "e", "f"}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}]
listdesired = Transpose[{{"a", "b", "c", "e", "f"}, {1, 1, 0, 2, 2}}]
```

I'd like to know an efficient method to produce `listdesired` from `list1` and `list2`.  In this case, the desired output is found by subtracting the integer in list1 from the item in list2 that has the same identifier ('a', 'b', 'c', ...).

**Update**

The solution that worked for me is reproduced below since it is currently in a comment and I would like the answer to persist.  The answer that has been accepted works just fine as well.

```
KeyValueMap[List]@*Subtract @@ KeyUnion[{Rule @@@ #2, Rule @@@ #}, 0 &] &[list1, list2]
```

Comment: `Transpose@*KeyValueMap[List]@*Subtract @@ KeyUnion[{Rule @@@ #2, Rule @@@ #}, 0 &] &[list1, list2]`?

Comment: @kglr no `Transpose` composition since I want the pairs, but yep! And thanks for using `Rule @@@ list` as I've been banging my head trying to remember that for some time now.

Comment: Little different ~ ```Sort@Join[list1, list2]
GatherBy[%, First]
Transpose /@ %```

Comment: Note that `Key` is another name for `Identifier` and there is a nice data structure that builds upon this called `Association`.

Comment: Also clunky: `Join[list1,list2]//GatherBy[#,First]&//Map@(PadLeft[#,{2,2}]&)//Map@({#[[2,1]], #[[2,2]] - #[[1,2]]}&)//Sort` 
Alternatively
`Join[list1,list2]//GatherBy[#,First]&//Map@({#[[2,1]], #[[2,2]] - #[[1,2]]}&@*(PadLeft[#,{2,2}]&))//Sort`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of a subtraction,
you can do  :

```
list1 = Transpose[{{"c", "a", "b"}, {2, 1, 1}}];
list2 = Transpose[{{"a", "b", "c", "e", "f"}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}];

Merge[{Rule @@@ list2, (#1 -> -#2) & @@@ list1}, Total] //KeyValueMap[List]
```

> {{"a", 1}, {"b", 1}, {"c", 0}, {"e", 2}, {"f", 2}}

Note that the second argument of Merge,`Total`, can' t do itself 
the subtraction, because it doesn' t know where a unique data is 
coming from (list1 or list2 ?)

More precisely, it depends on what you expect if there is an identifier in list1 that is not in list2.

Comment: A bit clunky, but we can bend Merge to our will: `KeyValueMap[List]@
 Merge[{Rule @@@ list2, Rule @@@ list1}, 
  If [Length@# == 2, Subtract @@ #, First@#] &]`

Comment: @bobthechemist If list1 contains an identifier that is not in in list2, for exemple `list1={{"a",1},{"b",8}}` and `list2={{"a",1}}`, your approach gives `{{"a",0},{"b" , + 8}}`. It is rather misleading.

Comment: @bobthechemist By "clunky" you mean the code, the text, or both ?

Comment: by clunky I mean it's *possible* to design a 2nd argument for Merge that performs the desired operation, but as you mention, it would take some work.  In my actual application, list1 only contains identifiers from list2, which is why I hadn't thought of that problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Association`s:

```
a = AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c", "e", "f"}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}];
b = AssociationThread[{"c", "a", "b"}, {2, 1, 1}];
Merge[{a, -b}, Total]
```

> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 2, "e" -> 2, "f" -> 2|>
>
> <|"c" -> 2, "a" -> 1, "b" -> 1|>
>
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 0, "e" -> 2, "f" -> 2|>

Oh, now I see that this is basically what andre314 proposed (minus some massaging). But this actually shows that `Association` might provide a better representation of your data as your data are key-values lists.

Comment: So very much clearer indeed; remember, humans read code, too. ;-)